# D3 Initial Zoom with default mercator projection scale

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having an issue specific to scale behavior with a default mercator projection scale value, in my case a pretty ridiculous value  (75000), since somehow it was the only way I was able to get my TOPOJson map to be project as anything other than a dot.

I created a projection of a map and want to add zoom and pan. My functions work, all except for the default zoom value. As soon as you scroll to zoom, the value jumps back to the default projection scale value, rather than scaling based on the mouse wheel. I have a feeling that the reason is because in order to get the map to display I needed to make my projection scale value really high (75000).

So when the page loads, the zoom looks fine, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yB80t.jpg)... but when you try to pan or zoom in or out one mouse wheel click, it jumps to [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1clAI.jpg)

I tried to limit the code to just the projection and zoom logic bellow.

```
<body>
  <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script></script>
  <script src="//d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <div id = "map" style = "float : left; min-width:320px;width :50%;height : 600px;"></div>
  <script>

  var width = 900,
  height = 800;

  var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
  .center([-73.94, 40.70])
  .scale(75000)
  .translate([(width/2), (height/2)]);

  var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
  .attr("viewBox", "0 0 900 800")
  .attr("preserveAspectRatio", "xMidYMid meet");

  var path = d3.geo.path()
  .projection(projection);

  var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-793.0489643729818,-630.1796382734433)scale(3.01487286910262)");

  d3.json("ny.json", function(error, ny) {
    g.append("path")
    .attr("id", "boroughs")
    .datum(topojson.feature(ny, ny.objects.boroughs))
    .attr("d", path);

// zoom and pan
var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
    .on("zoom",function() {
        g.attr("transform","translate("+
            d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
        g.selectAll("path")
            .attr("d", path.projection(projection));
  });

svg.call(zoom)

  });
```

Comment: The shapefile was downloaded from here: http://www1.nyc.gov/site/planning/data-maps/open-data/districts-download-metadata.page

Then i converted it with mapshaper

Comment: Can you post `ny.json` file someplace so that we can recreate your issue?  I like to use [jsonblob](https://jsonblob.com/)...

Comment: @Mark Ah! I was trying to use json editor online but it seemed to be too big... here you go: https://jsonblob.com/96ada11e-3285-11e7-ae4c-4b5e1959573f

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is that you set initial scaling and translate values for your `g` and then reset them on zoom. For scale, for example:

You set a scale for the `g` to 3.01 to start:

```
  var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(-793.0489643729818,-630.1796382734433)scale(3.01487286910262)");
```

However, the first time you zoom with d3.event, it'll return 0.607 or 1.647, (zoom out, zoom in) both are zoomed out relative to 3.01:

```
g.attr("transform","translate("+
   d3.event.translate.join(",")+")scale("+d3.event.scale+")");
```

This creates the jump you are seeing, as both scale and translate are reset and thus independent of your initial values. I think the translate value would be ok but you call it on the `svg` and not the `g` on which you specify the initial translate.

In any event, it is probably easier to not set an initial transform on your `g`, instead using the projection to do this (instead of a two step center and zoom with both a projection and a transform). That way you can leave all your code unchanged, save for removing the line setting the initial `g` transform and a modification to your projection.

Comment: That makes sense, my first attempt was trying to play with the translate values from the projection variable, however it seems to be mostly a guessing game and I can't get the zoom to work properly on the projection variable. So that's when I started trying to force it on the attribute on "g"... but yeah that's how I got to where I am now. I'm kind of stuck on how to get the translate attribute of projection to actually work with me

Comment: Hey I was actually just poking around on your blocks profile and came across this thing you made http://bl.ocks.org/andrew-reid/9556697440f43f576ed79cd5c445910e

I noticed you are using topojson that has a bounding box defined inside of it and you get the scale from that. Do you think this sort of approach would help me in this case?

Comment: Yeah, that should work, the projection parameters are set based on your json, then you can pan and scale the svg as needed (alternatively you can modify the projection when navigating the map, which is more demanding, but may also be preferred in some situations). d3v4 offers a more straightforward projection auto fit (fitExtent and fitSize)

Comment: after playing around with this method, it worked! Awesome! thanks